# Do you need an apostrophe if the noun proceeds the subject?

Tags: apostrophe

If I wanted to write out a sentence where the noun proceeds the subject, ie: the church of Christian's, would I need an apostrophe?

Comment: In your example, 'Christians' is just a plural. It is not a possessive. It is like saying 'a crowd of onlookers'. The possessive, in your example would be 'the church of Christ' which is a singular possession. I think that is why you have confused plural with possessive in this particular case.

Comment: Or, you may have meant to indicate a church that is owned or otherwise possessed by Christian. In which case, it could be as you wrote it, but it could also be "Christian's church," "the church belonging to Christian, "the church administered by Christian," and so on. Or, if it's a church that worships Christian, then it could be "the Church of Christian."

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the church to which a person called Christian belongs, then you need the possessive apostrophe. If you mean the church to which Christians (plural) belong, then there should no apostrophe.